# Probability of getting same number of black and white pebbles

Tags: probability, self-learning

I am trying to learn some probability and the following problem summarises my current confusion quite well.  Any help is gratefully received.

I have $n$ pebbles, some of which are black, some white and some neither black nor white. If I choose each one with probability $1/2$ independently, what is the probability that I get the same number of black and white pebbles?

Say there are $w$ white pebbles and $b$ black ones.

Comment: Not clear. How many times do we get pebbles?

Comment: @mathlove  Each pebble is either chosen or not with probability $1/2$.  On average you end up with $n/2$ pebbles chosen.

Comment: There's a big problem here: if you have three types of pebbles, you can't 'choose' each type of pebble with probability $1/2$, because then your total probability sums to $3/2$, while probability works only on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Newb I meant something a little different. Let's say the pebbles are lined up on a shelf but their color is hidden from you when they are on the shelf. You go to one after another and take it off the shelf with probability $1/2$.  You then look at the pebbles you have taken off the shelf and see if you have the same number of black and white ones.

Comment: I see! That's much clearer. You may want to clarify your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ denote the number of white pebbles that are chosen and $B$
the number of black pebbles that are chosen. Then you are looking
for:

$P\left\{ W=B\right\} =\sum_{k=0}^{n}P\left\{ W=B=k\right\} $

Here $P\left\{ W=B=k\right\} =P\left\{ W=k\wedge B=k\right\} =P\left\{ W=k\right\} P\left\{ B=k\right\} $
because of independence.

$W$ and $B$ are both binomially distributed. $W$ with parameters
$w$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ and $B$ with parameters $b$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This looks right.

Comment: I am worried that the events $W=k$ and $B=k$ are in fact not independent.  For example, if $W=n$ then we know $B=0$.

Comment: @marshall In my interpretation there are $n=w+b+c$ pebbles. $w$ of them are white, $b$ are black and $c$ is neither black nor white. Each pebble has a chance of $1/2$ to be chosen. Then $W$ takes values between $0$ and $w$, $B$ takes values between $0$ and $b$ and they do not affect eachother, so there is independence. I don't exclude the possibility that my interpretation is not correct, but uptil now this is all I could make of it.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.